# Test Categories which are not categories squelettiques?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Are there any examples of test categories which are not *categories squelettiques* in the sense of Cisinski?

*Categories squelettiques* are a type of generalized Reedy category, discussed for example on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+Reedy+category) under the name "Cisinski-generalized Reedy category".

Comment: "the category whose objects are finite totally ordered sets, or finite ordinals, and whose morphisms are order-preserving functions between them." ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category#Definition)) and this is equivalent to the simplex category, hence is a test category.

Comment: There are two things you could mean by "skeletal category". There's the usual categorical meaning of "isomorphic objects are equal". There's also Cisinski's notion of a  _categorie squelletique_, a kind of [generalized Reedy category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+Reedy+category). Because the property of being a test category is stable under equivalence of categories, every test category is equivalent to a skeletal one in the first sense. As for the second meaning, I'd guess that "most" test categories are not skeletal in this sense, but are harder to work with.

Comment: They are plenty. For instance the catégory of euclidian spaces and $C^\infty$-maps. If $A$ is local test, then for any Cartesian fibration $p\colon C\to A$ is also local test. In particular, if $p$ has weakly contractible fibers and if $A$ is a test category, so is $C$ a test category. There is no reason that such a $C$ has nice combinatorial properties. For instance, if a small category $C$ is weakly contractible, then $A\times C$ is a test category for any test category $A$.

Answer (score 2):

One class of examples comes from the fact (cf. Cor 4.1.22 in Cisinski, *Les Prefaisceaux Comme Modeles des Types d'Homotopie*) that if $A$ is a test category and $B$ is any category with contractible classifying space, then $A \times B$ is a test category.

So take $A$ to be your favorite test category (e.g. $A = \Delta$ is the simplex category), and take $B$ to be your favorite weakly contractible category (e.g. $A$ could be a big directed poset). Then $A \times B$ is a test category, but it probably isn't a *categorie squelettique*, even if $A$ *is* a *categorie squelettique*.

Comment: Oh, I see now that Denis-Charles has mentioned this (and other more interesting examples) in the comments before me.